# Delete node binaries

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, binary

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wonder if it is possible to delete the binary files of a particular node from a workspace because I want to replace its source file with another one of the same name and generate a new binary file from the new source file. If I just replace the source file, it won't generate a new binary file when I do catkin_make. Right now, I'm deleting the devel and build folders to delete all the binary files.

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284366/delete-node-binaries/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2018-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Replacing the source should work, as `make` should detect that it has changed and then proceed to build the new binary. If that doesn't work then that would be considered a bug.

As to the binaries themselves: they are located in `$CATKIN_WS/devel/lib`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2